# How to fix dynamic imports errors 'cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') in nextjs?

Tags: next.js, dynamic-import

```
  import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

    const DynamicSerialize = dynamic(() => import('next-mdx-remote/serialize'));
   const parseMDX = async (content) => {
     const turndownService = new TurndownService();
     addRules(turndownService);
     const markdownContent =     turndownService.turndown(content);
    const options = {
      mdxOptions: {
      rehypePlugins: [rehypeSlug],
     remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm],
   },
 };
    return await       DynamicSerialize(markdownContent,  options);
  };

  export default parseMDX;
```

I'm getting error on calling 'dynamicSerialize'

Server Error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

I tried checking all my files that call the mdxParser function have awit and sync